# Sencha native app error st-res/templates/stbuild_template_sim.app/ does not exists

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-cmd

I'm trying to build a native application from sencha cmd using sencha app build native and everything seems to work fine until it gets to this part:

failed running native packager
[ERR] Source directory: st-res/templates/stbuild_template_sim.app/ does not exists
Error copying st-res/templates/stbuild_template_sim.app/ to /home/dethstar/public_html/muhapp/build/muhapp/native/muhapp.app/
Failed to package application

But I Haven't been able to find anything about these files, neither online or in the touch directories. Any idea?

Comment: I'm having the same problem- any progress?

Comment: Did u fix it? if yes Pls post the answer

Answer (score 0):

I had to link st-res and stbuild into my working directory:

```
ln -s /opt/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.0.203/stbuild/stbuild
ln -s /opt/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.0.203/stbuild/st-res
```

"/opt/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.0.203/" needs to be replaced with the path to your Sencha CMD installation.